# Can I install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 2008 Server Standard SP1

Tags: frameworks, windows-server-2008, .net-4.5

I have Windows server 2008 standard service pack 1 with .Net FrameWork 3.5 sp1, can I install 
Microsoft 4.5 framework without installing Microsoft framework 4.0 before?

Also if you [look at the system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653#system-requirements) you will see that prerequisite is Windows Server 2008 SP2 while I have only SP1 and it seems I can't install SP2.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 4.5 on Win2K8 Server and it installed fine (without installing 4.0 prior).

NOTE:  In IIS the application pool will still show up at 4.0 although the 4.5 install succeeded.